# Xcode seems not to find all 'init' signatures for UIBarButtonItem

Tags: xcode, swift

I am trying to use `UIBarButtonItem` with the following signature:

```
init(barButtonSystemItem systemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem,
              target target: AnyObject?,
              action action: Selector)
```

But xcode seems not to accept this signature, since it displays this error:

> Missing argument for parameter 'style' in call

This is what I am doing:

```
cell.imageView!.image = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Add, target: self, action: "test")
```

UIBarButtonItem has other signatures for `init`, so I guess xcode is not finding the signature above. Am I doing something wrong?

Here is a link for UIBarButtonItem class reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBarButtonItem/initWithBarButtonSystemItem:target:action:

Comment: The type of `cell.imageView!.image` is `UIImage?`, and you cannot assign a  `UIBarButtonItem()` to it. The compiler message is misleading, but that assignment is definitely wrong. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to put an icon on "cell", where "cell" is an UITableViewCell object. I checked the documentation and, indeed, "cell.imageView!.image" must receive a UIImage object... So, any tips on how to make it work? I also checked UIImage documentation, but I couldn't find a way to make it work. Thank you.